# perl system command redirection to log files

Tags: perl

I am trying to redirect perl system command to output file with the following code  along with time but its not working ??

```
$cmd="echo hi";
($second, $minute, $hour) = localtime();
$time="$hour:$minute:$second";

system("$time>new.txt");

system("$cmd   1>>new.txt 2>>&1");
```

Comment: showing error The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want to write the variable `$time` to a text file, `open` a writeable filehandle and print it to your file instead.

```
open(my $outfile, '>', 'new.txt');
print $outfile $time;
...
```

Secondly, your output redirection should read:

```
1>>new.txt 2>&1
```

Which means "append STDOUT (1) to new.txt, redirect STDERR (2) to STDOUT (1)". Having `>>` makes no sense for the second part.

Finally, I (and every other perl programmer) would strongly recommend using `strict` and `warnings` pragmas in your scripts. This will help you pick up on any errors or potential problems in your scripting. Once you've done this, all variables must be declared with `my`, which is a good habit to get in to anyway. So after all that, your script should look something like this:

```
# recommended pragmas:
use strict;
use warnings;

# declare all new variables with "my"
my $cmd="echo hi";
my ($second, $minute, $hour) = localtime();
my $time="$hour:$minute:$second";

# open a writeable filehandle and print to the filehandle
open(my $outfile, '>', 'new.txt');
print $outfile $time,"\n"; # I've added a newline character here so that 
                           # the time and the command's output are on different lines ;)

system("$cmd   1>>new.txt 2>&1");
```

Comment: yup thnks !!Having >> makes no sense for the second part correct as its a file handler i think it should work